# Stuck on Type Mismatch

Tags: scala, types, compiler-errors

I'm working through [99 Scala Problems](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/) and have run into a snag on [#27 - Group Elements of a Set into Disjoint Subsets](http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/#p27).  I have written a helper function of sorts which does all the work, the only problem is I'm getting a **type mismatch error**.  Here's the function:

```
def addGroupN[T](gs: List[List[List[T]]], n: Int): List[List[List[T]]] = {
  gs.flatMap(xss => combinations(n, list diff xss.flatten).map(xs => xss :+ xs))
}
```

The `list` is of type `List[T]` and the function `combinations` returns a `List[List[T]]`.  The compiler is computing this to be typed as `List[List[List[Any]]]`, hence the mismatch with the signature.

I'm less concerned with style/idiomatics suggestions, than I am with better grasping how to properly reason about type evaluation.  In addition to answering how to properly write this to match the correct signature, something which would indicate how this function in its current form could return anything *other* than a `List[List[List[T]]]` would also be helpful.

---

#### Edit:

The full signature of `combinations` is

```
def combinations[T](n: Int, list: List[T]): List[List[T]]
```

Comment: Please, add signature of `combinations` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How exactly is `list` a `List[T]`?

`T` is a generic parameter of method `addGroup`. If `list` is defined outside the method, then it cannot be a `List[T]` with the same `T`.

Supposing you have

```
class YourCode[T]  {

   val list: List[T]

   def addGroup[T](....)

}
```

the `T` parameter in `addGroup` just hides the `T` in `YourCode`, they are two different types.  You can rename it e.g `U` without changing anything, except making it clear. Doing that, in `list diff xss.flatten`, `list` is of type `List[T]`, `xss.flatten` is `List[U]`, `T` and `U` are two different type parameters which can be just anything (no bounds) the best common supertype is `Any`, so the `diff` is a `List[Any]` instead of the expected `List[T]`. From there, you get `List[List[List[Any]]]` at the end.

Comment: +1 Yeah, that's exactly the explanation I was looking for as to how the compiler is evaluating the type. Could you also include how to properly capture `list` in the scope of `addGroupN[T]` method so that it is a `List[T]`? I've found that explicitly adding an `ls: List[T]` parameter to the method and manually passing in `list` achieves the correct evaluation. I assume there is better way.

Comment: It depends on your context. If you have a list[T] outside the method (which means you have type T in context, as in my small example) and your addGroup method will combine its input with a list[T], then the addGroup method is simply not generic. It accepts only values of the enclosing type T, and not of any type, which the addGroup[T] implies.  So just write `def addGroup(gs:List...[T], ...)` rather than `def addGroup[T](...)`

Comment: Oh! That makes total sense now. Yeah, I don't actually need this internal function to be generic...I was actually just adding the `[T]` without really thinking about it. Thanks, this really clarified a lot for me.